# Get and store id from database to different table based on user search input

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple dynamic textboxes where users input license plate no. I'm trying to retrieve the id corresponding to the license plate # inputted by the user from the database but I'm unable to get it. I want to store the **license plate #'s *id*** that's already in the database to a different table and not the license plate no itself, but It always returns null.

Thanks in advance.

### search.js

```
function firetruckAddingTextBoxes() {
var NumOfText = $("#NumOfTextBoxes2").val();
$('.NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes2').empty();
var txtBox = "";

for (i = 0; i < NumOfText; i++) {
    txtBox += '<input type="text" name="firetruck[]" class="search" placeholder="License Plate No" required/><br>';
}
$('.NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes2').append(txtBox);



$(".NewlyCreatedSelectBoxes2").on("keyup", ".search", function () {
    var search_term = $(this).val();

    $('#search_results2').html('Searching database...');

    if (search_term !== '') {
        $.post('php/firetruck_search.php', { search_term: search_term }, function (data) {
            $('#search_results2').html(data);
        });
    } else {
        $('#search_results2').html('Not Found');
    }

});
return false;

}
```

---

### search.php

```
<?php
require('connectdb.php'); 

if(isset($_POST['search_term']))
{
    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['search_term']));

    if(!empty($search_term))
    {
        $search = mysql_query("SELECT `fireTruckID`, `licensePlateNo` FROM `firetruckinfo` WHERE `licensePlateNo` LIKE '%$search_term%'");
        $result_count = mysql_num_rows($search);

        $suffix = ($result_count != 1) ? 's' : '';
        echo '<p>Your search for ', $search_term, ' returned ', $result_count, ' result', $suffix, '</p>';

        while($results_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($search))
        {
            echo '<p>', $results_row['licensePlateNo'], '</p>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

---

### occurrence.php

```
$firetrucks = $_POST['firetruck'];
        foreach($firetrucks as $firetruck):
            $vehicleID = mysql_query("SELECT `fireTruckID` FROM `firetruckinfo` WHERE `licensePlateNo`='$firetruck'");
            $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($vehicleID);

            $query3 = "INSERT INTO `truckonscene`(`FireTruckInfo_fireTruckID`, `IncidenceOfFire_incidentID`)
                   VALUES(
                   '".mysql_real_escape_string($row2['fireTruckID'])."',
                   '".mysql_real_escape_string($incidentid)."')";

            mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
        endforeach;
```

Comment: I know this gets posted all the time, but mysql_* is deprecated, please try to switch to mysqli as soon as you can. As an "is it plugged in" question, is your license plate field a character type as you are referring to it, or is it a numeric type?

Comment: Check if your query in `php/firetruck_search.php` is correct. Add debug messages in form of `echo 1`, `echo 2` in various places to detect where it exists without result.

Comment: The php/firetruck_search.php worked ok. My problem is when the user enters a 'license plate no' in the textbox i want to be able to retrieve the 'id' from the database that corresponds to the 'license plate no' and store the **license plate no's id** and not the license plate no itself@Grzegorz